# How to determine the real memory usage of a single process?

Tags: linux, memory, memory-management

How can I calculate the real memory usage of a single process? I am not talking about the virtual memory, because it just keeps growing. For instance, there are *proc* files like *smaps*, where you can get the mappings of a process. But this is virtual memory and the values of that file just keeps growing for running process. But I would like to reflect the real memory usage of a process. E.g. if you plot the memory usage of a process it should represent the allocations of memory and also the freeing of memory. So the plot should be like an up and down movement instead of a linear function, that just keeps growing for a running process.

So, how could I calculate the real memory usage? I would appreciate any helpful answer.

Comment: So to clarify, when you say "real memory", you really mean something like a running calculation of space currently malloc'd (and not freed), correct? This is known as the "live size" of a process.

Answer (score 3):

It's actually kind of a complicated question.  The two most common metrics for a program's memory usage at the OS level are *virtual size* and *resident set size*.  (These show in the output of `ps -u` as the `VSZ` and `RSS` columns.)  Roughly speaking, these tell the total memory the program has assigned to it, versus how much it is currently actively using.

Further complicating the question is that when you use `malloc` (or the C++ `new` operator) to allocate memory, memory is allocated from a pool in your process which is built by occasionally requesting an allocation of memory from the operating system.  But when you free memory, the memory goes back into this pool, but it is typically *not* returned to the OS.  So as your program allocates and frees memory, you typically will not see its memory footprint go up and down.  (However, if it frees a lot of memory and then doesn't allocate it any more, eventually you may see its rss go down.)

Comment: So, what do you recommend? Is there a way to get the necessary information to calculate the real memory usage of a process?

Comment: Well, it may end up being one of those "it depends on how you define 'real memory'" issues.  In my book if the virtual memory size keeps growing, it means you've got a memory leak.  You may be able to get away with one of those for a while, but not in a long-running process.  If you really only care about how much physical memory your process has allocated to it, rss and/or maxrss are probably close to what you want.

Comment: Also, there are some Related Questions to the right that look relevant!

Comment: I am talking about the physical memory. But rss is not really reliable. There values such uss and pss, which are more reliable values in regarding to the memory usage of a process. But rss is not very satisfying. So, this means, there is no way to get the physical memory usage of a process?

Comment: I'm not sure about this (and I again encourage you to explore the related links to the right), but in a virtual memory environment, asking youw much physical memory your program is using is an ephemeral and not-particularly-relevant statistic, which may be one reason it's hard to pin down.  It can change based not only on what your process is doing, but also based on what other processes on the system are doing: if you've allocated memory that you're "not using", the OS may take the physical memory away if other pricesses need it, but not if they don't.

Comment: It's not a perfect analogy, but in a VM environment, assessing the memory performance of your program by looking at physical memory usage is a little like measuring your net worth by looking at the amount of cash in your wallet.